# Test if computer object exists in Active Directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory

I have a problem checking if a computer object exists in AD or not. To be specific it should go into an "else" if not.

This is my code:

```
if (Get-ADComputer "$Computer") {
        Get-ADComputer $Computer | Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false
        Start-Sleep -s 2 
        Get-ADComputer $Computer | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $PathOU
        Start-Sleep -s 2 
} else {
    write-host "Example"
}
```

When the input computer doesn't exist, the problem is, the command `Get-ADComputer "$Computer"` already fails in the `if` statement, so it never reaches the `else`.

How can I avoid that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Try Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3) instead:

```
try {
    Get-ADComputer $Computer | Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false
    Start-Sleep -s 2 
    Get-ADComputer $Computer | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $PathOU
    Start-Sleep -s 2 
catch {
    Write-Host "Example"
}
```

Comment: this may not always work; you should add to the cmdlet `-ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: @Avshalom Not really in this case. AD Cmdlets produce pipeline terminating errors always

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Get-ADComputer` to a variable before the `if` block to help. Also before setting that variable with the command, set it to null per the below example. In addition to that, change up the `if` block to first check if it does not exist and to run that logic first then `else` run logic if it does exist.

```
$comp = "";
$comp = Try {Get-ADComputer "$Computer"} Catch {$false};

if (!$comp) {
    write-host "Example"
    } else {
        $comp | Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false
        Start-Sleep -s 2 
        $comp | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $PathOU
        Start-Sleep -s 2
    };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [if](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)

  > `!`      logical not